# how to retrieve video path and display video like youtube from mysql database in php.?

Tags: php, mysql, video

I have stored video path in mysql database & actual video stored in upload folder but i want to display that video with controls in my page using database path.

I have tried but video not loaded that video.

I have seen following error in console,

**GET http://localhost/new_ci/admin/%3C?=$video_path;?%3E 403 (Forbidden)**

please suggest to me..?

Tried following code:

```html
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
       mysql_select_db("demo",$con);?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 </head>
<body>
 
<div id="body">
 <table width="80%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <th colspan="4">your uploads...<label><a href="index.php">upload new files...</a></label></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     
     
    <td>View</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
 $sql="SELECT * FROM video";
 $result_set=mysql_query($sql);
 while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_set))
 {
  $pat ="upload/"; 
  $pat1 ="http://localhost/new_ci/admin/upload/";
  $path = $row['video_name'];
    $vid = $pat1.$path
  ?>
        <tr>
   
        <td>
  <?php 
  echo "<embed src=".$vid."  />";
  echo "<video width='320' height='240' controls> <source src=".$pat.$path." type='video/mp4'>Your browser does not support the video tag.</source></video>"; ?>
  <video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="upload/How To Host A PHP Website From Your Home Computer (Localhost).mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</source></video>
  </td>
         </tr>
        
 <?php
 }
 ?>
    </table>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your video folder is protective. you have to change the permission of that folder to access it.

Comment: @MahaDev How to change permission..?

Comment: First paste here the exact url of your video

Comment: Use $vid inside video source too.

Comment: @MahaDev I have already do that but not working..?

Answer (score 2):

Replace your td with this my code:

```
<td>

<embed src="<?php echo $vid ?>">
<video width='320' height='240' controls> <source src="<?php echo $vid ?>" type='video/mp4'>Your browser does not support the video tag.</source></video>
<video width="320" height="240" controls> <source src="upload/How To Host A PHP Website From Your Home Computer (Localhost).mp4" type="video/mp4">Your browser does not support the video tag.</source></video>
</td>
```

Comment: Its working but some file format like wmv,3gp or any.

Comment: so how to do that things..?

Comment: You have to define a type for every video type you use. like you defined type = 'video/mp4'.

Comment: how to add more video type..?

Comment: Inside your while loop, check video extension and assign it to a variable and then use that variable inside your video tags

Comment: Well its a separate topic. Atleast i deserve a single upvote. :P

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93034/discussion-between-dnyan-and-maha-dev).